# how to Automatically Copy Data Between Google Sheets by script editor and write a date day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

For daily capital tracking, I must copy a number from a cell and paste it into a blank cell and write today's date in front of it automatically in Google Sheets by script editor
[image]

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: should the script run once a day only or everytime K1 changes?

Comment: There's no trigger which fires on changes made my other scripts or formulas.

Comment: The script should only run once a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function onEdit(e){
   //suppose your source data is on k1.
  let range = e.range.getA1Notation();
    //suppose the value you want is always on K1
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(range === 'K1'){
    const source_value = ss.getRange('K1').getDisplayValue();
    const ddd = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,9,1,2).setValues([[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'GMT -5','yyyy-MM-dd'), source_value]]);
  }
}
```

If you need a day or time Trigger, you can add one accordingly.